# aframe add camera rotation by player

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr, oculusquest

I test aframe in VR mode with oculust quest 2 and I can't get what I want for the player movement.

Currently I am moving forward or backward and right or left but only with the right controller.

I would like to be able to move with the left controller (not the right) and be able to change the rotation of the camera with the right controller.

How to do it please?

this is what I use for the moment

```
<a-entity  movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true" position="0 0 2" >
    <!-- Camera -->
    <a-entity id="camera" camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls></a-entity>
        
    <a-entity  id="leftHand" hand-controls="hand: left; handModelStyle: highPoly;" ></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="rightHand" hand-controls="hand: right; handModelStyle: highPoly;" ></a-entity>
```

thanks

Comment: have you solved this?